# vim script: how to change "put =" to an append?

Tags: vim, scripting

I'm trying to hack the c-vim plugin because I don't like the way it inserts comments. I want this:

```
/* comment */
```

but it gives me this:

```
/* comment
 */
```

I'm sure it has its reasons, but I don't like it. So I'm digging through the c.vim file and I've found this:

```
function! C_CodeComment( mode, style )
   if a:mode=="a"
     if a:style == 'yes'
       silent exe ":s#^#/\* #"
       silent put = ' */'
     else
       silent exe ":s#^#//#"
     endif
   endif
   if a:mode=="v"
     if a:style == 'yes'
       silent exe ":'<,'>s/^/ \* /"
       silent exe ":'< s'^ '\/'"
       silent exe ":'>"
       silent put = ' */'
     else
       silent exe ":'<,'>s#^#//#"
     endif
   endif
 endfunction
```

I have not been able to find any documentation on the `put =` statement, which I'm pretty sure is the one I have to change in order to get vim to append `*/` to the last line of the comment. Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: I think you'd have better luck dropping the `put` lines and changing the `s`... (substitute) lines to include the `*/`

Answer (score 3):

The function `C_CodeComment` is not defined in any of the files that come with recent versions of Vim. I searched a bit and it looks like you are using [Fritz Mehner’s C/C++ plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=213). It provides a *C/C++* > *Comments* > *code -> comment /* */* menu item (and a `\c*` mapping<sup>1</sup>) that uses `C_CodeComment`.

The command `put = ' */'` appends a new line (see [`:help :put`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Aput)) that contains the contents of the [special register `=`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#quote%3D), which just evaluates whatever comes after it as a [Vim expression](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expression-syntax). The particular expression used here is just a simple three character string (space, asterisk, forward-slash).

You can arrange for `*/` to be at the end of the last line<sup>2</sup> by adding a line like

```
silent normal kJ^
```

after the `silent put = ' */'` lines. It moves up to last commented line (`k`), joins it with the `*/` line (`J`), and then moves the cursor to first non-blank character of the line (`^`); the `\co` mapping<sup>1</sup> itself includes a `j` to move the cursor to next line after the newly commented region.

However, doing **this will break the assumptions of the `C_RemoveCComment` function** (which is used by the `C_CommentCode` “inverse” function): it expects to find and process `*/` at the beginning of the line (after optional whitespace).
If you never use the *C/C++* > *Comments* > *comment -> code* menu item or the `\co` mapping<sup>1</sup>, then you may be able to live without the ability to use this plugin’s uncomment feature.

---

<sup>1</sup> The `\` “leader” of the mappings might be different if you have redefined [`localmapleader`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#maplocalleader).
<sup>2</sup> This (in my opinion) makes for odd looking multiline comments (i.e. selecting more than one line via GUI selection or visual mode before invoking the commenting functionality):

With the middle two lines  selected,

```
    foo();
    bar();
    baz();
    quux();
```

becomes

```
    foo();
/*     bar();
 *     baz(); */
    quux();
```

which seems like an odd style (typically, if `*` leaders are used on intervening lines, then the asterisks from the `/*` opener, the `*` leaders, and the `*/` ender are put in the same column).